# How to filter files by size in google cloud storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to find files that size is less than 10k in google cloud storage.

```
gsutil ls -l gs://my-bucket/
```

This `gsutil` command shows list of files with sizes.
Is there a option for filtering the list by file size?

I'll write a script for it, if there is no default option is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsutil ls doesn't support filtering by size. You could do it with a script like this:

```
gsutil ls -l gs://your-bucket | awk '/gs:\/\// {if ($1 > 10000) {print $NF}}'
```

Comment: anyone have this but also handles file names with spaces?